# RStudio automatically loading packages when starting up

Tags: r

When I open a project in RStudio (in Windows), there are now a number of pre-loaded packages that are loaded ("ROCR" and its dependent "gplots").

This never used to occur and I'm wondering if someone could please advise how I can modify the start up procedure to avoid any non-'standard' packages being pre-loaded.

I realise that I can go to Tools --> Global Options and deselect "Restore .RDdata into workspace at startup", however this also stops all the other objects being loaded which I do need.

Similarly, I'd rather not create a new project and essentially clear everything as I have a lot of objects that I want to continue using which would be a pain to re-create.

Thanks in advance!

Phil

Comment: I'll avoid espousing an opinion about clean environments and suggest setting `options(defaultPackages = "")` in your `~/.Rprofile` and/or `R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=""` in the `~/.Renviron` and see if that prevents R from loading other packages it thought necessary from the `.RData` ingestion. Alternatively, get in the habit of running `ls()` (watch for hidden objects, too) and `rm()`-ing what you don't need before closing down.

Comment: OK, I lied abt not espousing an opinion. What's stopping you from using `save()` OR (better yet) create a list of objects you want and use `saveRDS()` (and their counterparts)? OR, keeping the crazy save/load setting but at an Rproj level? I personally use `saveRDS()` and the amt of time it takes for a deliberate load has never been a problem (and I generate many and large-ish objects as well).

Comment: Thanks for your help hrbrmstr.
Unfortunately it didn't seem to work when I made the modifications to .Rprofile and .Renviron as suggested above. I might need to create a fresh project and, as you said, ensure that I keep the environment as clean as possible.

I hadn't actually come across saveRDS() before. I'll look into that.
Thanks again,
Phil.